# Pandas and Py2exe ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, py2exe

I have created an executable using py2exe of a Tkinter program. The .py file runs perfectly without any errors. However, when I run the executable, I get a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis from the following line:

```
df = df[df['A'] != 'X']
```

The df looks like this:

```
    'A'    'B'    'C'
0    X      4      7
1    2      5      8
2    3      6      9
```

The line should filter out row 0. As I stated before, it works perfectly when I run the python program, but the executable gives me the above ValueError. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you by any chance have multiple versions of `pandas` installed on your machine?  One possibility is that `py2exe` is bundling a different version of `pandas` than the one you normally use, and in the one `py2exe` is using, there's a bug, or a missing feature.

Comment: So, what version of pandas do you have, and do you have any other versions installed anywhere?

Comment: I only have pandas 0.13.1 installed on my machine. No other versions anywhere else.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but sometimes they're hard to find.  If you're not 100% sure, to verify, you could add some sort of `log(pandas.__version__)` to your code and see what it spits out from the executable program.

Comment: Sorry how can I actually show this log of the pandas version? Not sure where or how to put it in my code...

Comment: So I just printed the pandas version, and when I run the executable it gives me 0.13.1.

Comment: Sorry - not sure what's going on then.  The only suggestion I can think of is upgrade `pandas` to version 0.14.1; that's the version I use and I can't replicate your problem - works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was coming from another function that I called before, applymap. When I removed this, the GUI seems to work fine. Py2exe doesn't seem to like applymap for whatever reason.